# write a program that prompt user to enter a telephone number

Tags: c

I am writing a program that promts the user for a telephone number in the form (xxx) xxx-xxxx and then displays the number in form xxx.xxx.xxxx in C language.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {    
    int d1, s2, d3;

    printf("enter phone number[(xxx) xxx-xxxx]:"); //phone number to be entered
    sscanf("%d %d-%d", d1, s2, d3); //to read input in above format
    printf("you entered %d.%d.%d", d1, s2, d3);

    return 0;
}
```

My problem is that `scanf` is unable to read data entered with `()` round brackets.

Comment: your scant format isn't asking for the round braces.

Comment: In most cases, actually, the better solution for human (as opposed to rigorously-formatted file) input is to fetch the input line and parse it yourself. You can recover from variations in the input much more easily than sscanf() can.

Comment: Looking closer... you don't mean to use sscanf, you mean to use scanf! also, you need to pass the _address_ of the variables you're scanning into, not the variables themselves.

Answer (score 5):

You meant to use `scanf` instead of `sscanf`. Also, you should memory address of the variable to be written into to `scanf`. You should change the format string of `scanf` to `""`. `scanf` returns the number of input items assigned successfully. Check this value for `3` to find if the input was entered in the required format.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {    
    int d1, s2, d3;
    int val; // to check if scanf was successful

    // newline causes the string to be immediately 
    // written to stdout

    printf("enter phone number[(xxx) xxx-xxxx]:\n"); 
    val = scanf("(%d)%d-%d", &d1, &s2, &d3);

    // check if scanf was successful
    if(val == 3)
        printf("you entered %d.%d.%d", d1, s2, d3);
    else 
        printf("input not in the correct format.\n");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: scanf("(%d)%d-%d", &d1, &s2, &d3);

Comment: hi sayutee,ajay,mah,keshlam, thanks for your comments it works now

Comment: Hi sayutee, it is working without using a variable int val just using scanf("(%d)%d-%d) a desired output  is coming so can you please shed some light why int  val was used.

Answer (score 2):

You can get the input into a string. e.g.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define NUMBER_LEN 14 //the number of characters in the string (the phone number)

int main()
{
    char phone[NUMBER_LEN];
    printf("enter phone number[(xxx) xxx-xxxx]: ");
    gets(phone);
    printf("You entered %s", phone);
    return 0;
}
```

Further, you can play with your string and format it.

Comment: Maybe the use of `fgets()` would be more appropriate than `gets()`. Get good safety habits going early. I upvoted your answer because it doesn't use `scanf()` without explaining its caveats. I'm almost certain this question will result in a follow up on how `scanf()` is automatically hitting enter for some reason :)

Answer (score -1):

Use scanf instead sscanf(" %c", &char);

Comment: This answer doesn't make any sense.

Comment: Indeed the original suggestion to replace scanf with scanf made no sense. I edited the answer to suggest replacing sscanf with scanf which is a valid improvement to the code in the question and must be what guy actually meant.

Answer (score -1):

This is a simple program which reads the entered numbers as a array of characters that is string and simply prints these numbers : -

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>

void main(){

  char phone[16];

  printf("Enter mobile number: ");

  scanf("%s",&phone);

  printf("Your Mobile Number is: %s",phone);

  getch();
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please be aware that "code only" answers are not considered really good answers. You might add some explanation why this may be better than the other provided answers. Besides that you have same errors as in your identical answer to other question. Please also consider spending a few more moments to verify the formatting of your answer before you continue and provide same answer on multiple questions.

Answer (score -3):

```
int main(void)
{
    int a, b, c;
    printf("Enter phone number: [(xxx) xxx-xxxx]: ");   scanf("(%d)%d-%d", &a, &b, &c);
    printf("You entered: %d.%d.%d", a, b, c);
    return 0;

}
```